# Complicated cases expression

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to insert this expression in my Latex file:

[image]

When I start entering :

```
\begin(cases)
```

I got an error saying “ unrecognizable environment “

I tried this ( nested arrays) :

```
MA_{c_1,c_2}(i,j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
Max(i,j), &\text{if min(i,j)=0}\\
Min & {\begin {array} {lr}
\end{array}
\end{array}
```

When I start the nested array , document review disappeared.

I need help “coding” this expression in Latex .

I am using Texstudio as a Latex editor.

Comment: Used editor is not relevant to your problem. Please show us what you try so far.

Comment: I searched online i found this command (\begin(cases)) , but this command is not available in Latex ..l

Comment: of course, it is :-) . Of course, t should not be enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Are the lower brackets really cases, or is it just the minimum of three different expressions? In the latter case I would typeset the formula in a way that this gets reflected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for cases*, also load amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
xxx = \begin{cases*}
    \max(t,f) & if $\min(t,f) = 0$   \\
\min\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
    xxx & + 1 \\
    xxx & + 1 \\
xxx xxx & + 1 \\
    \end{array}\right. &  otherwise
        \end{cases*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your text is very hard to read (which is why most likely some characters are misrepresented below). Yet I could not make sense of having `\min` in front of cases. So I am wondering if the lower part, i.e. the second case, is the minimum of a list. If so, maybe the following is more appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 MA_{C_0f_0}(i,j)=
 \begin{dcases}
  \max(i,j) & \text{if}~\min(i,j)=0\;,\\
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}l@{}l@{}}
  \min\bigl\{
    &MA_{C_0f_0}(i-1,j)+1,\\
    &MA_{C_0f_0}(i,j-1)+1,\\
    &MA_{C_0f_0}(i-1,j-1)+1\bigr\}\\
  \end{array}& 
  \text{otherwise}\;.
 \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]